# Kafka Connect Skipping Messages due to Confluent Interceptor

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am seeing following messages in my connect log

`WARN Monitoring Interceptor skipped 2294 messages with missing or invalid timestamps for topic TEST_TOPIC_1. The messages were either corrupted or using an older message format. Please verify that all your producers support timestamped messages and that your brokers and topics are all configured with log.message.format.version, and message.format.version >= 0.10.0 respectively. You may also experience this if you are consuming older messages produced to Kafka prior to any of those changes taking place. (io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringInterceptor)`

I have changed my kafka broker with this

```
KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL_VERSION: 0.11.0
KAFKA_LOG_MESSAGE_FORMAT_VERSION: 0.11.0
```

I am guessing this is reducing my overall producer throughput and I am trying load testing.

PS:
I don't want to remove the confluent interceptor because it helps me with throughput and consumer lag.

```
CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
```

Any way to not skip those messages, I am using [pepperbox](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box/) to produce messages and it doesn't have timestamp

```
{
        "messageId":{{SEQUENCE("messageId", 1, 1)}},
        "messageBody":"{{RANDOM_ALPHA_NUMERIC("abcedefghijklmnopqrwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRWXYZ", 2700)}}",
        "messageCategory":"{{RANDOM_STRING("Finance", "Insurance", "Healthcare", "Shares")}}",
        "messageStatus":"{{RANDOM_STRING("Accepted","Pending","Processing","Rejected")}}"
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Kafka version in the pom, and you'll see it's using Kafka 0.9

Timestamps were added to Kafka as of 0.10.2.

As the error says `Please verify that all your producers support timestamped messages`.

Recompile the project with a new version, and all produced records will automatically have a timestamp, and therefore not be skipped.

Or, use a different tool like JMeter or Kafka Connect Datagen.

Comment: Ahh thank you! I didnt notice pepperbox has dependency too. I thought it will be superseded by the version in which kafka runtime is ran. But makes more sense now. I will try upgrading kafka version and see if it compiles first.